# Detecting monitor changes on OSX

Tags: macos, notifications, screen

I have an app which asks for notifications about monitor changes so as to reconfigure, and these are currently not getting triggered if I add a monitor:

```
    [[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                        selector:@selector(distNotificationHook:)
                                                            name:NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParametersNotification
                                                          object:nil];


    [[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                        selector:@selector(distNotificationHook:)
                                                            name:@"com.apple.BezelServices.BMDisplayHWReconfiguredEvent"
                                                          object:nil];
```

They used to work.. but no longer. Anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue is that this needs to use NSNotificationCenter, not NSDistributedNotificationCenter:

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                        selector:@selector(distNotificationHook:)
                                                            name:@"com.apple.BezelServices.BMDisplayHWReconfiguredEvent"
                                                          object:nil];
```